# VBA Read txt file line by line and save each line to the new excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a txt-file, which contains several raws (> 1000). I want to read this file line by line and copy them every time to the new excel worksheet (cell A1). Each raw of the txt-file contains the excel formulas, which are used to generate the data request from financial database via Internet. So each time it must extract the data from the database. I tried to write the code by myself, well I tried out two possibilities to read the data line by line, but I get the error message for the line, where I write the line to the cell:

```
Sheet_i.Cells(1, 1).Value = TextLine
```

I do not understand, where do I made a mistake.

Here is my first code, it uses fso:

```
Sub ReadtxtFileIntoSeveralSheets()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject: Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim txtStream As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim i As Long 
Dim Sheet_i As Worksheet

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the file you want
Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\excel\formula.txt", ForReading, False)

i = 0 'to offset column for each line

' Read the file one line at a time
   Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream

    TextLine = txtStream.ReadLine 'read line
    ' create new active worksheet

    Set Sheet_i = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    'paste the line to A1

     Sheet_i.Cells(1, 1).Value = TextLine

    i = i + 1
Loop

' Close file
txtStream.Close


Set txtStream = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

And here is my second code:

```
Sub Data_copy_several_sheets_2()

Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String
Dim Sheet_i As Worksheet

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open "D:\excel\formula.txt" For Input As #FileNum

 While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
    Set Sheet_i = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

    Sheet_i.Cells(1, 1).Value = DataLine 'fill cell

 Wend
 Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Could anybody help me to accomplish this task?

Comment: what error message do you get? and what is the value of `TextLine` when it errors out?

Comment: Is your `TextLine` a valid Excel formula? You may need to do some clean-up, e.g. trim carriage returns and/or line feeds from the end. Not sure it makes a difference, but you might try writing to `Cells(1,1).Formula` instead of `.Value`.

Comment: The error message is 1004 “Object-defined error”. Textline is the formula that I generate in Excel first and then copy to the txt file. Something like WENN(A1>1;1;0), but much more complicated, since it is a request that is used to retrieve data from the external database. Each request must be generated in Excel first and can be exercised one at a time using special Excel-Add-In. I cannot leave the formulas in Excel (since all requests will be active at once), so  I have to copy them somewhere and then copy back one by one and simultaneously retrieve data each time in the new worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheet_i.Cells(1, 1).Value = DataLine
```

Should be

```
Sheet_i.Cells(1, 1).Formula = DataLine
```

you might also want to trim that line and remove any excess white spaces just to be safe:

```
Sheet_i.Cells(1, 1).Formula = Trim(DataLine)
```

---

If you're still not getting anywhere then make sure the correct application settings are in place:

```
Sub SwitchOnDefaults()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. `Sheet_i.Cells(1, 1).Formula = Trim(DataLine)` unfortunately did not helped. I also used Sub SwitchOnDefaults() before, also without any results. I still get error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”.